# How to generate data for both history and current?

Tags: sql

I need to generate a report from existing tables with scd stored.

Imagine I have following tables:

table1

```
| Pid |               eff_dt |               exp_dt |
|-----|----------------------|----------------------|
| 489 | 2018-11-02T05:27:12Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
| 546 | 2018-11-02T05:27:12Z | 2018-12-02T05:27:12Z |
| 546 | 2018-12-02T05:27:12Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
```

table2

```
| Pid |  val |               eff_dt |               exp_dt |
|-----|------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 489 | JD7G | 2018-11-02T05:24:16Z | 2018-11-09T05:40:47Z |
| 489 |  JD7 | 2018-11-09T05:40:47Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
| 546 | TR56 | 2018-11-09T05:40:47Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
```

Expected Output is :

```
| Pid |  val |               eff_dt |               exp_dt |
|-----|------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 489 | JD7G | 2018-11-02T05:27:12Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
| 489 |  JD7 | 2018-11-02T05:27:12Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
| 546 | TR56 | 2018-11-02T05:27:12Z | 2018-12-02T05:27:12Z |
| 546 | TR56 | 2018-12-02T05:27:12Z | 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z |
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of keeping eff_date and exp_date and also tag the appropriate database rather than tagging multiple database.

Comment: @GaneshDogiparthi . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could be more specific. Any way in `mysql` you may run the simple script:

```
Select table1.Pid, table2.val, table1.eff_dt, table1.exp_dt 
From table1 Join table2 
On(table1.Pid=table2.Pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic for keeping eff_dt & exp_dt is not that clear in your post. Anyway I have kept both values from your table1. (workable for most of the database you tagged ;) )

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Pid,T2.val,T1.eff_dt,T1.exp_dt 
FROM table2 T2 
INNER JOIN table1 T1 ON T2.pid = T1.Pid
```

The output is as below-

```
Pid val     eff_dt                      exp_dt
489 JD7     2018-11-02 05:27:12.049     9999-12-31 23:59:59.000
489 JD7G    2018-11-02 05:27:12.049     9999-12-31 23:59:59.000
546 TR56    2018-11-02 05:27:12.049     2018-12-02 05:27:12.049
546 TR56    2018-12-02 05:27:12.049     9999-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

You can also check the results in [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d0f0ce52c656ca99ffeec0ab831e8da2)